# How to get html-tags autocomplete in sublimetext3 on react (js) files?

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext3

How can i get back the function
of autocomplete html tags in react files (.js)

example : 
type li + press tab to get

```
   <li></li>
```

i already installed the plugin reactjs
what gave me some advanced autocomplete features,
but not for simple html.

Answer (score 0):

1. press `Ctrl + Shift + p`
2. type `Install package`
   A dialogue box will open,
3. Type `emmet` and run it by double click on `emmet` or press enter

once emmet install just type any html tag and press tab,

for creating `<li></li>` just type **li** and press tab,

for creating a UL with 5 li, type `ul>li*5`

for creating 5 li in ul with anchor type... `ul>li*5>a`

there are lots of shortcuts for such things...

and if you want to get JSX support thenm go to `Preferences > Key Bindings — User` and paste this code

```
{
"keys": ["tab"],
"command": "expand_abbreviation_by_tab", 
"context": [
    {
        "operand": "source.js.jsx", 
        "operator": "equal", 
        "match_all": true, 
        "key": "selector"
    },
    {   
        "key": "selection_empty", 
        "operator": "equal", 
        "operand": true,
        "match_all": true 
    }
]
}
```

Enjoy

Comment: hey atul, thanks so much for a reply to me. this does not work for me. 
on .html files i still have this autocomplete. not on .js files.
can this somehow overlap with other rules / plugins ?